# Looking for product target definitions for using M2Doc with Sirius 7

Tags: m2doc

I'm looking for the up to date list of plugins required for M2Doc to successfully work on top of Sirius 7.0 (or later) without any clashes. Preferably as a .tpd file or .target file.

Any help will be appreciated.
I'm currently using a previous .tpd file
(https://github.com/IAI-Cyber/TRADES/blob/master/releng/dsm.TRADES.parent/tp/target.tpd)
which includes m2doc 3.2.2 and Sirius 6.5.1, and when I try to update to Sirius 7.0.0 or above there is a conflict with a Sirius component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the list of target platforms [here](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/tree/master/releng/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.targetplatforms), older ones are probably not up to date and might have some issues. But you will find a target for Sirius 7.1.0.

You will then need to add the update site for the M2Doc [release](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/releases) you want to use.